# VisualStudio Build Tools 2017 offline installer

Tags: visual-studio-2017, build-tools, build-server

I generate an an offline installer for the build tools like this:
**`vs_BuildTools.exe --layout c:\VS_BuildTools2017_offline --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --lang en-US`**

I move this folder to a build agent (which has no internet connection, and no, it will never have one!), and then execute the  **`vs_BuildTools.exe`** in that folder even with **`--noWeb`** or **`--noweb`**, but no matter what option I give, it will always fail with no internet connection available. Surely I am missing something, so any hints on what are appreciated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I also had problems with this.

One important step is to install the certificates before running the installer on the target machine:

- Install the certificates, they are in the "certificates" folder, which is in your Layout folder. Right-click each one to install it. Remember to install the certs using the Admin account on the PC. I.e. not just for the current user.
- Run the installation file.

Answer was originally posted [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/54883/view.html).

In addition I also noticed that when running the installer on the offline machine it has by default selected some more items than what was downloaded. I had to deselect them to *only* install the build tools, not the SDK and so on...

<s>But still the install failed, I am currently seeing "An installation file did not download" so I have still not managed to complete the whole install. It's `microsoft.visualstudio.vc.msbuild.arm64.vsix` maybe it's included in some other component that have to be `--add`ed.</s>

**Update**: Nevermind, my last problem was due to not using `--noweb`, with it there were no errors.

Answer (score 81):

All steps to install build tools:

1. [Download build tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/thank-you-downloading-visual-studio/?sku=BuildTools)
2. Download layout files for offline installation:

   - Possible workloads are specified [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools). Following command contains workloads for msbuild and C++ build tools.
   - Run (exe file will have some version numbers in name): vs_BuildTools.exe --layout c:\BT2017offline --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.WebBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCoreBuildTools --lang en-US
3. Copy c:\BT2017offline to box on which you want to install it.
4. Open mmc and import all certificates from c:\BT2017offline\certificates to "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" of **computer** (not current user)
5. Run (exe file will have some version numbers in name): c:\BT2017offline\vs_BuildTools.exe --noweb
6. Continue clicking next ...

Comment: Warning: You cannot install on Win Server 2012 R1 :)

Comment: i'd like to advise to add `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet.BuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack` as [it is listed here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/137779/the-getreferencenearesttargetframeworktask-task-wa.html)

Comment: When adding the certs it asks you for a password. I later found out you just leave them blank and continue.

Comment: I have it on Win Server 2012R2

Comment: Will any of these components require a .NET Framework upgrade beyond version 4.5.2?

Comment: I followed these instructions exactly and everything went well until step 5.  It seems to be ignoring the --noweb instruction.  The installer times out and says it can't access the network to download the files.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Worked great, and also works for VS 2019.  BTW, if you are unsure how to use mmc here is a good [step by step guide on importing certs](https://support.globalsign.com/customer/en/portal/articles/1217281-import-and-export-certificate---microsoft-windows)

Comment: Also probably good to note, that if you are modifying an existing installation of the build tools, you still need to use `--layout` to build your new cache, but you **do not** use `--noWeb' on the target machine at that point, instead you have to updated the response.json as discussed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/controlling-updates-to-visual-studio-deployments?view=vs-2019)