# MSBuild offline installer that comes with visual studio 2017 build tools not able to build project in Release mode

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, msbuild, release

**Step 1** - I have installed visual studio build tools by downloading
**vs_BuildTools.exe** from [this site](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=visual%20studio%202017) (you will require to login to microsoft account to browse this URL)

**Step 2** - I created offline installer by following various articles particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46684230/visualstudio-build-tools-2017-offline-installer)

And created zip file **offlineBuildTools17.zip**

**Step 3** - Copied **offlineBuildTools17.zip** file to Build server which doesn't have internet connection.
Build server is Windows server 2012 R2.

**Step 4** - Extracted Zip file on server and installed Build tools. Installation goes smoothly.
I could see installation files in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\Microsoft
```

**Step 5** - I have simple DLL and Console application (.exe) project in my solution. These are simply 'hello world' application **NOT USING DOT NET CORE**. I am using .net frameowrk 4

**Problem:** I am unable to create release mode dlls and exe

Same thing is working on my laptop where I have installed visual studio 2017 community edition.
On laptop where visual studio 2017 installed

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild"  <optional project.csproj> /p:Configuration=Release
```

This creates dlls and exe in **bin\Release** folder of project

But the same doesn't work on Build server.
Always creates dlls and exe in **bin\debug**  folder.
My final goal is to create 'publish' folder

Comment: Enable MSBuild diagnostic logging on both machines and compared the successful and failed cases. You should be able to easily identify the cause from the diff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is weird but it is solving my problem.
if i ran following command - msbuild is always generating Debug binaries. which was my original problem. it doesn't generate release mode binaries at all

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\"msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /t:publish /p:OutDir="./Publish"
```

But if i write following command , (note **how msbuild is placed in double quote** along with mbuild full path) it is working fine. it generates release mode binaries and also publish folders.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\msbuild" /p:Configuration=Release /t:publish /p:OutDir="./Publish"
```

thanks